# Double integral changing variables

Tags: calculus

> Calculate  $\int\int_{R}\frac{x-3y}{2x+y}dxdy $ where $R$ is a parallelogram built on the sides of the following line $y=-2x+1$, $y=-2x+4$
>   $y=\frac{2x}{3}$, $y=\frac{x-7}{3}$

How should I approach this? I understand that I need to change variables, but why is it?

Thanks to the comments I came to the following:

$x=\frac{u+3v}{7}$, $y=v-\frac{2(u+3v)}{7}$

The points of intersection of the parallelogram are (clockwise):$ (\frac{1}{7},\frac{3}{7}),(\frac{12}{7},\frac{12}{14}),(\frac{7}{10},-\frac{7}{5}),(\frac{19}{7},-\frac{10}{7}),$

the jacobian is $6$

Comment: do you mean to solve for $\,dy\,dx?$

Comment: @Nehorai I have guidance which says to solve it using change of variables

Comment: $$x:=a u+b v$$
$$y:=c u+d v$$  from $x,y$ plane to $u,v$ plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

use the substitution:

$$
\begin{cases}
u=x-3y\\
v=2x+y
\end{cases}
$$

this simplify the integrand and also the limits of integration.

---

Hint 2:

The limits of the area becomes:
$$
y=\frac{x-7}{3} \rightarrow x-3y=7 \rightarrow u=7
$$
$$
y=-2x+1 \rightarrow 2x+y=1 \rightarrow v=1
$$
$$
y=-2x+4 \rightarrow 2x+y=4 \rightarrow v=4
$$
$$
y=\frac{2x}{3} \rightarrow x+u=0 \rightarrow 3v+8u=0
$$

and the Jacobian:
$$
\left|\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} \right|= \left|\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} \right|^{-1}=
\left|
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} 
\end{pmatrix}
 \right|^{-1}=
\left| \begin{pmatrix}
1&-3\\
2&1 
\end{pmatrix}\right|^{-1}
=\frac{1}{7}
$$

can you do from this?
( I suggest you to calculate the area with the new coordinates and with the old $(x,y)$. It's a good exercise!)

Comment: You are correct for $x$ and $y$ .... really i've not found all the intersection points :)

Comment: So how do I find the limit of integration now?

Comment: Hint: the Jacobian that you needs for the change of variables is $\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}=1/7$

Comment: I0ve added something to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I am finally starting to understand this

Comment: Why did you take the inverse of the Jacobian?

Comment: I've added to the answer.